# App "Not Verified" after iOS 9.0.2 update

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been developing an iOS app and as of 3 days ago I was able to load it onto my iPhone 6s without any issues. The only thing I can think that may have changed is that I updated the phone to iOS 9.0.2 2 days ago. I am using a free account and have not paid the $100 yet.

This morning when trying to launch the app I get this error. When I click "Verify App" I get the message: "Verifying will use your network connection to see if the app from this enterprise developer can be used on your iPhone." But when I click Verify, nothing ever happens.

[image: error]

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you launched the app directly from the device instead of from XCode? Usually you have to do this the first time. 1. Press ">" in XCode. 2. Get error. 3. Launch app on device 4. Confirm message 5. You're good

Comment: Make sure that you have internet connection, otherwise running the application with a free provisioning profile won't get verified and will show that screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are testing you application on free developer team, without requiring enrollment at $99 fee.

> Apple has dropped the requirement to register as a developer in order
>   to test your apps on your device. You can now create and install any
>   app you want using the public iOS SDK available in Xcode on the Mac
>   App Store.

To be sure click on your project and go to **General -> Identity -> Team** and see if you are using your free team. If that so, it is required to have an internet connection as mentioned on the screen:

> Verifying will use your network connection to see if the app from this
>   enterprise developer can be used on your iPhone

It think Apple is using this logic in terms of security (Not sure though), but the only thing to do is to enable internet on the device, verify it and run it.

Comment: That was the issue. I thought I had a good connection but apparently my WiFi connection was bad. Thanks for your help.